# Slim down steam overlay

Tags: steam

I would like to remove most of the stuff that comes "out of the box" with the steam overlay. Specifically the Friends, Achievements, Guides, Screenshots, Community Hub and Discussions boxes.

I know I can take away the whole overlay by clicking <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>. But isn't it possible to just have the friends list?

[image: Screenshot of the overlay taking up very much space]

Answer (score 1):

Install the new [Steam Beta](https://store.steampowered.com/news/collection/steam/?emclan=103582791457287600&emgid=3695810094455933105), the new Overlay is really toned down, and has all of that stuff just on the sidebar.

While it still doesn't allow you to remove them, I think you will enjoy it